# Bash completion own compgen prefix

Tags: bash, autocomplete, compgen

I have a simple bash completion script that essentially invokes my (non-bash) program and set its output to `COMREPLY`, i.e.

```
COMPREPLY=( $(my-program -- "${COMP_WORDS[@]}") )
```

Some of the options accept comma separated value, is there a way to handle suggestion only for the last item? Let's say the user types `-v opt1,opt2,o<TAB><TAB>`, let's say my program finds out the the valid options at this point are `opt3` or `opt4`. If I just return those 2 and press TAB the output changes to just `o` (entire prefix gone). It works if I return `opt1,opt2,opt3` and `opt1,opt2,opt4`, but that doesn't look nice.

Possible solution is to do something like [Bash completion for comma-separated values](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124539/bash-completion-for-comma-separated-values), that is, invoke `my-program` to generate `[opt3, opt4]`, and pass that as word list to `compgen` with `opt1,opt2,` as prefix. But that requires duplicating some logic in the bash script as in `my-program` . Is there a better way?